# Trying to port ng-bootstrap example, but ngbDropdownToggle working

Tags: angular, dropdown, ng-bootstrap

I'm new to Angular and Bootstrap, so apologies in advance if this question is somewhat basic and a bit wide-ranging.

For testing/learning purposes, I'm trying to port into my new project the `"Mixed menu items and form 'Toggle Dropdown'"` Stackblitz example from https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples, and while I can get the HTML to render, I can't get the dropdown button to toggle.

I tried **two** approaches:

1. I created a project, and then copied in the relevant src/app files from the Stackblitz collection into the project's src/app folder (i.e., `app.component.html`, `app.component.ts`, `app.module.ts`, `dropdown-form.html`, `dropdown-form.ts`). Under this approach, the HTML rendered but the dropdown didn't toggle.
2. As a second attempt, I tried copying the entire Stackblitz collection into its own folder, and tried to run `ng serve` on it. Under this approach, nothing compiled and there were a lot of error messages, starting with `Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" . . .`

One particular question I had is where does the `ngbDropdownToggle` Directive reside?

i.e., from `dropdown-form.html`:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownForm1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
```

On Stackblitz, I noticed a dependency in package.json for `"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap"`, and wondered if the ngbDropdownToggle Directive resided there, but when I tried to add that dependency into the package.json file in my original project, the compiler complained: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'`. My working assumption is that my original project is missing some key `ng-bootstrap` imports/functionality, but I'm not sure if this is correct, and if so, how do I add the necessary imports/functionality?

Many thanks in advance if anyone has any ideas how I can port in the Stackblitz files and make the dropdown toggle work . . .

Comment: After adding the dependency, did you run npm install? this should resolve both your devkit and ng-bootstrap error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get it working on stackblitz, you need to add a dependency `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` (check screenshot below)

to get it working on your PC, you do `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

Also, you need to the boostrap css `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />` in you index.html

[image]

[working demo](https://stackblitz.com/angular/onqyobneeka)

Comment: Many thanks @Akber Iqbal and @KiraAG. I performed `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` and added the `.css` links in `index.html`, (I even manually added `"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap":"4.1.0"` to `package.json` then ran `ng serve` but the result is still the same. The HTML renders, but the dropdown doesn't toggle. Any further thoughts? Tks!

Comment: Further clarification: I can get the Stackblitz example to work properly on my computer, but when I create a new Angular project (`ng new dropdown`), then copy in the `app` files from the Stackblitz example, add the @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap dependency to `package.json`, add the `.css` links to `index.html`, run `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`, and then `ng serve` I still can't get the dropdown to toggle.

Comment: Somewhat embarrassed to say, that in addition to the spot-on comments from @Akber Iqbal and @KiraAG, I had forgot to `import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` in my imports, and add `NgbModule` to `@NgModule` imports. So now it works! and many thanks for the replies.